# Facebook app center, translation of "detailed description" field returns error

Tags: facebook, translation, appsettings

I have my default language set as English (US) in the facebook app settings.
The "detailed description" field is filled with english language content.
In the section "Translate your app for additional languages" I have "detailed description" field with original english gray fade color text.
When I paste there the text translated into polish and trying to save it, I get the error message:

"Błąd
Oryginalne zdanie, na którym oparte jest tłumaczenie już nie istnieje.
There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later."

which means:
"Error
Original sentence, the translation is based on doesn't exist any more.
There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later."

The rest of the translated fields are saveable for translation, only the "detailed description" doesn't allow to save translation. Do you have any idea, what is going on. Does anyone had this kind of problem. I couldn't google any solution to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this kind of problem before with the translation features on FB.

Firstly - if you use completely different text for testing purposes does that save?
If you get the same error with any text at all entered it would suggest the problem is not the content by that Facebook has a bug with the system.

You can report bugs to Facebook at:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

If alternative content works - try editing your content, it may be that there's a special character or similar (perhaps not even visible) that is breaking things. Pasting the text into a plain text editor like notepad and copying back out can help strip those kind of things.